# get a character from a string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I have this string:

```
String code="abc";
```

i want to extract "c" from this string by `substring` method but it doesn't work:

```
String code="abc";
String getsmscode=code.substring(2,1);
```

This code return an error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; regionStart=2; regionLength=-1
```

but i don't know why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to read [the documentation for substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) - the second parameter isn't a length, it's the end index (exclusive).

> **Parameters:**
>       `beginIndex` - the beginning index, inclusive.
>       `endIndex` - the ending index, exclusive.

When in doubt, read the docs...

Also note that if you're just trying to get the final character, you can just use the single-parameter overload, which returns a substring from a given start point to the end of the string:

```
String lastCharacter = text.substring(text.length() - 1);
```

Or you could get it as a single character:

```
char lastCharacter = text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: but when i do this: substring(2,1); i dont get anything!!

Comment: @FarhadShirzad: No, you get an exception... if you use `substring(2, 3)` you'll get the last character.

Comment: @FarhadShirzad your start index can't be after your end index. you never will get anything that way (other than the obvious exception). the method is basically substring(start, end). does 2 come before 1?

Comment: @FarhadShirzad You can also use String.charAt(position); to get single character from the given string.

Answer (score 7):

Second parameter is not a length, it is [an end index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

```
  String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

The guys above have answered your question adequately but just a few tips on reading the API.

Methods usually start with the word public and then include the return type... that is what type of data will be returned. If nothing is expected to be returned is void.

Then comes the name of the method and two parenthesis.

In between the parenthesis are the parameter type it accepts.

with this particular method it accepts two integers. these help keep an index of how much of a string you'd like to keep

index is an important concept to understand and it's hard to describe how it all works in words but looking at the examples in the api description listings help.

index-1 usually means counting starts at 0 so in the String "Hello World" H is indexed 0 and d is index 10. Notice there are only 9 letters but we still must include the space as a character so it's index in this case is 5.

it's important to note the api mentions excludes and includes in the parameter descriptions. This just means the returned string will include the letter indexed by the first parameter but will not include the letter indexed by the second parameter.

if all you need to do is extract the last letter in a string, no matter how long the string size, a simple solution is

```
stringName.substring(stringName.length()-1);
```

Comment: thanks for you'r perfect words... thank you. i solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The index start from 0. You can try

```
String code="abc";
String getsmscode=code.substring(2);
```

Comment: That doesn't extract the last character. The OP has just misunderstood the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think substring takes a start index or a start index and end index as parameters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You've given it a start index greater than the end index, hence it is getting confused as the length returned is then negative. Swap the 1 and 2 around.

Comment: Swapping 1 and 2 will return b. The end index character is excluded.

Comment: Yeah. I was more responding to the lack of understanding of the parameters the function expected for the person to correct themselves, rather than providing an exact solution. Apologies, I'll stick to rules next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use can achieve this like also.

```
String getsmscode = code.substring(2,3);
```

Method Description

```
public String substring (int start, int end)
```

Returns a string containing a subsequence of characters from this string. The returned string shares this string's backing array.

> **Parameters**
>
> start - the offset of the first character.
>
> end- the offset one past the last character.

Returns a new string containing the characters from start to end - 1

Throws

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException   if start < 0, start > end or end > length().
```